# How to write multiple url for diff pages using php and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need multiple url rewriting method for my web page.
I am able to work with one url rewriting using PHP and htaccess as:
index.php page code
PHP code:

```
       $retvalue=$_POST["packagestring"];
     $_SESSION["package_string"] = $retvalue;
    header("location:package/".php_slug($retvalue)."");
}
function php_slug($string)  
{  
    list($packageid, $packagename) = explode(":",$string);

   $url = $packageid."/".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $packagename));
  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($url)));  
  return $url;  
}
```

When I click on the button, via post method of index page i jump to package page with the url as:
http://localhost/xyz/package/2/temp-temp-temp

as this package page contains one submit button and when i click on this usbmuit button i want to go to book_package page with the below url:

http://localhost/xyz/book_package/2/temp-temp-temp

but I am getting as 
http://localhost/xyz/package/2/book_package.php

Here is the working htaccess file with url and not with second url

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images)/(.*)$ $1
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ package.php?packagestring=$1  
RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ package.php?packagestring=$1 
RewriteRule ^xyz/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301] 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^book_package/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ book_package.php?booknow=$1  
RewriteRule ^book_package/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ book_package.php?booknow=$1 
RewriteRule ^xyz/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Below is the code for package page for url rewriting:

```
if(!isset($_GET["packagestring"])){
  header('location:index.php');
 }elseif(isset($_GET["packagestring"])) {
  $getpackage = $_GET["packagestring"];
```

}
    function php_slug($string)
    {
        list($packageid, $packagename) = explode(":",$string);
       $url = $packageid."/".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $packagename));
      $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($url)));
      return $url;
    }

```
 if(isset($_POST["booknow"])){
   $retvalue=$_POST["booknow"];
    var_dump($retvalue);
    header("location:book_package.php");
}
```

Any one suggest me that how to implement this

Comment: Very unclear what you’re asking, resp. what you are even trying to achieve here. You are talking about POST requests - please don’t say you use those for the actual page navigation (which should happen via GET) …? And where does this need any rewriting to begin with, this rather sounds as if you simply didn’t specify the `action` of the forms you are submitting correctly …?

Comment: Or are you talking about the redirects you are making after processing the send POST data? Well then specify _proper_ URLs in there, instead of just using `header("location:book_package.php")` …?

Comment: I am making url after post of index and package pages.
When i click on button of index page I jump to package page with accurate url as http://localhost/xyz/package/2/temp-temp-temp

When i click on button of package page i want to jump on book_package page with url as http://localhost/xyz/book_package/2/temp-temp-temp

and that is not happening? I am getting the url as :
 http://localhost/xyz/package/2/book_package.php

I think its clear now, if not plz intimate me

Comment: No, not much clearer than before. _“I am making url after post of index and package pages”_ - no clue what that is supposed to mean. _“When i click on button of index page I jump to package page with accurate url as localhost/xyz/package/2/temp-temp-temp”_ - and what is the purpose of “jumping” there? If you just want the user to switch to a different page in this first step, then why is this a POST form(?) to begin with - why are you not using a proper link for _this_? _“I am getting the url as : ”_ - again, most likely because you specified a wrong relative URL in this place to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 pages as 
1. index.php
2. package.php 
3. book_package.php and I want to traverse in the order 1->2->3
index page partial code as:

```
if(isset($_POST["packagestring"])){
    $retvalue=$_POST["packagestring"];
     $_SESSION["package_string"] = $retvalue;
    header("location:package/".php_slug($retvalue)."");
}
function php_slug($string)  
{  
  list($packageid, $packagename) = explode(":",$string);
  $url = $packageid."/".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $packagename));
  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($url)));  
  return $url;  
}
```

ON POST request, I am getting packagestring value as "2:temp temp temp"
Now, I want to jump to package.php with user firendly url and thats why I created a slug function that convert packagestring to 2-temp-temp-temp and location will be as package.php

htaccess file code is:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images)/(.*)$ $1
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ package.php?packagestring=$1  
RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ package.php?packagestring=$1 
RewriteRule ^xyz/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301] 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^book_package/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ book_package.php?booknow=$1  
RewriteRule ^book_package/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ book_package.php?booknow=$1 
RewriteRule ^xyz/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Above code will help me to make userfriendly url as
localhost://xyz/package/2-temp-temp-temp
instead of localhost://xyz/package.php?packagestring=2:temp temp temp
by getting the packagestring in package.php file as:

```
if(!isset($_GET["packagestring"])){
 header('location:index.php');
}elseif (isset($_GET["packagestring"])) {
 $getpackage = $_GET["packagestring"];
}
```

Its fine upto here means package.php page Now, I want to jump to book_package.php and below is the package.php POST code when i click on package book button:

```
 function php_slug($string)  
{  
    list($packageid, $packagename) = explode(":",$string);
   $url = $packageid."/".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $packagename));
  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($url)));  
  return $url;  
} 

if(isset($_POST["booknow"])){
  $retvalue=$_POST["booknow"];
    var_dump($retvalue);
    header("location:book_package.php");
 }
```

and below is the book_package code to get the string value :

```
if(!isset($_GET["booknow"])){
   header('location:index.php');
}elseif (isset($_GET["booknow"])) {
    $getpackage = $_GET["booknow"];
    var_dump($getpackage);
}
```

This time the requested file is book_package and the htaccess code is mentioned on the above..

Here I am not able to get as well as jump to book_package.php page
I am on the same page (package.php) but with new url as:

```
http://localhost/xyz/package/2/book_package.php
```

Here I want 
    http://localhost/xyz/book_package/2/temp-temp-temp

I think this is okay

Comment: It seems that no one worked with multiple rule. Quiet strange ?

Comment: hi, the above issue has been resolved by me...
Many Thanks